# android: how to add item to an array list

Tags: android, arraylist

I want to add all item from photo's folder to arraylist and below is my code -

here is my model

```
public class Model {
    private String image;

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

here is my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Model model;
    private ArrayList<Model> alPhoto;
    private File file;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        alPhoto = new ArrayList<Model>();
        String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        file = new File(root_sd + "/photo/");
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

    //      alPhoto.add(list[i].getName());

            model = new Model();
            model.setImage(alPhoto.get(i).getImage());
            alPhoto.add(model);

            Log.e("Load image from sd card******* :    ", "Loading...." + alPhoto.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am unable to set image to arraylist as showing array index outof bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
{
        String strPath = list[i].getAbsolutePath();
        Log.e("Checking path",">>"+strPath);

        Model model = new Model();
        model.setImage(strPath);
        alPhoto.add(model);

        Log.e("Checking arraylist",">>"+alPhoto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your for a loop. You declare model globally so which is added only the last item in list is your problem instead of declare locally in for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
// alPhoto.add(list[i].getName());

        Model model = new Model();
        model.setImage(alPhoto.get(i).getImage());
        alPhoto.add(model);


        Log.e("Load image from sd card******* :    ", "Loading...." + alPhoto.get(i));

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still showing error like this.
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.demogridview/com.example.android.demogridview.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: Before for loop check with condition list.length>0